# how to correct this javascript?

Tags: javascript

could you please help me to allow the asyncFileUploader to use these extensions:(rar,pdf,doc,docx,zip)...

im not an jscript expert, so i have been tying to edit the script by my self but i failed ...

```js
var fileExtension = args.get_fileName();
if (fileExtension.indexOf('.doc') != -1) {
    $get("dvFileErrorInfo").style.display = 'block';
    $get("<%=lblError.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "File extension [.doc] not supported";
    $get("dvFileInfo").style.display = 'none';
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to `fileExtension.indexOf('.doc') == -1 && fileExtension.indexOf('.pdf') == -1 && etc` so on. Copy paste the condition and add the extensions you wanna allow. This would mean that any extensions not in the conditions will fullfil the condition and the message will display

Comment: removing the condition will allow all types of files, what i need is to edit the script to allow only (zip,rar,pdf,doc,docx) types only . thnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnClientUploadStart` property on the control to fire a JavaScript function for validation, like this:

```
<cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" 
  OnClientUploadStarted="AssemblyFileUpload_Started" />
```

Then use this script on your page:

```
<script>
function AssemblyFileUpload_Started(sender, args) {
    var filename = args.get_fileName();
    var ext = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    if (ext != 'zip') {
        throw { 
            name:        "Invalid File Type", 
            level:       "Error", 
            message:     "Invalid File Type (Only .zip)",
            htmlMessage: "Invalid File Type (Only .zip)" 
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Use other file types as well.